# Regex does not contain certain words

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am looking for a regex expression that will exclude the below words from a huge text file/files.

```
@author
@Autowired
@Override
@param
@SuppressWarnings
```

I have tried with this but does not work as expected.

```
@[^(author)(Autowired)(Override)(param)(SuppressWarnings)].*
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript`?

Comment: @Viswa shmosel has a good point... to answer the question correctly, we really need to know what language you're using.  If you're writing a Node.js program to process Java sources, then you should have only the "javascript" tag.  If you're writing a Java program, you should have the "java" tag.  It makes a difference because there are regex features that are supported by some languages and not others.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the following *regex (using [negative look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))* :

```
@(?!author|Autowired|Override|param|SuppressWarnings).*
```

*see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/8OGr9F/1)***

Comment: siam: Thanks a lot, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Square brackets in regexes are used for character classes.  When you put a list of characters in square brackets, this matches **one character** that is one of the ones listed.  So

```
[author]
```

matches *one* character, if it's `a`, `h`, `o`, `r`, `t`, or `u`.  It does not look for the word `author`.  Putting `^` in front also looks for one character that *isn't* in the list:

```
[^author]
```

matches one character as long as it's not `a`, `h`, `o`, `r`, `t`, or `u`.

But the key thing here is that `[]` cannot be used to match words or other sequences.  In your example,

```
@[^(author)(Autowired)(Override)(param)(SuppressWarnings)].*
```

the part in square brackets matches one character that is not `(`, `a`, `u`, or any of the other characters that appear in the square brackets (many of those characters appear multiple times, but that doesn't affect anything).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
@(?!author|Autowired|Override|param|SuppressWarnings)\S+
```

Basically, it looks for a `@` that is **not** followed by that list of words, and then it matches any non-whitespace characters after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To flip the script, if you're actually trying to take the text file and *remove* things that are in your list of keywords, you'll probably want to find those using syntax more like this: `@(author|AutoWired|Override|param|SuppressWarnings)\b`.  The terminal `\b` is just a precaution to avoid @authority or other unlikelihoods.